# What is supposed to happen with flex-basis: column,wrap?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am experimenting with css and specifically this HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="child">
        <h1>Some random text</h1>
      </div>

      <ul class="child">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="child">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    background:#1c1c1c;
    width:200%;
}

header {
    display:flex;
    background:#000;
    padding-top:18px;
    justify-content:space-around;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

`wrap` seems to have no effect when using a flex direction of: column.  What is supposed to happen? If I reduce the vertical size of the browser (meaning the items do not fit), then should the items wrap into two columns? If I reduce the vertical size of the browser to a minumum then a vertical scroll bar appears?

I have read the docs for flex-wrap here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap and I have looked here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.   Everywhere I look seems to assume you are using a flex direction of row if wrapping.  I cannot find an explanation of what is supposed to happen if a flex direction of column is specified.

Comment: If I reduce the vertical size of the browser (meaning the items do not fit), then should the items wrap into two columns? Yes.

Comment: @pilchard, I have added html and css to my original post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
#example-element {
border: .75em solid;
padding: .75em;
width: 40%;
float: left;

display: flex;

flex-flow: column wrap;

}

#example-element>div {
background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
border: 3px solid #00f;
width: 60px;
margin: 10px;
}

.short {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 200px;
}

.tall{
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example-element" class="transition-all short">
            <div>Item One</div>
            <div>Item Two</div>
            <div>Item Three</div>
            <div>Item Four</div>
            <div>Item Five</div>
            <div>Item Six</div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="example-element" class="transition-all tall">
            <div>Item One</div>
            <div>Item Two</div>
            <div>Item Three</div>
            <div>Item Four</div>
            <div>Item Five</div>
            <div>Item Six</div>
        </div>
```